# Add the existing column "References" to a new xlsx with the outputs

Tags: python, pandas

I need some guidance here. I know that I'm probably making this too complex, but I'm quite new on the Python world. I'm learning and trying to do some useful stuff. So, this is my present task and issue:

I have two xlsx files. Let's call them "New" and "Old". Both files have a column named "References" that work as unique IDs.

I start to check if the References on the file "Old" are present on the file "New", so I can get all the "References" that were removed.

After I check if the "References" on the file "New" are present on the file "Old" or not, so I can retrieve all the new references.

Finally, I check if there was any changes on the column "Prices" of both files.

With the new outputs I generate a new file that basically has 3 sheets with the result of each output.

I'm near my goal, but I would like also to have the original column "References" in each new Sheet, so it would be easier to detect the changes.

My description is sounding too confuse! But I hope that my code can help to understand what I want to do:

```html
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from pandas import ExcelFile
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)

df = pd.ExcelFile('C:\\Users\\A\\Desktop\\Scraps\\cap_30_04t.xlsx')
sheet1 = pd.read_excel(df, 'Antigo')
sheet2 = pd.read_excel(df, 'Novo')

nao_existe = sheet1['Ref'].isin(sheet2['Ref'])  #os falsos são os que não existem

print(nao_existe)

novos = sheet2['Ref'].isin(sheet1['Ref'])  #aqui os que derem Falso são os novos

print(sheet2['Ref'], novos)

precos = sheet2['Preço'].isin(sheet1['Preço'])  #ver se houve mudança de preço

print(precos)


# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('C:\\Users\\Andre\\Desktop\\Scraps\\filename6.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

nao_existe.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='nao_existe')
novos.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='novos')
precos.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='preco')

# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()
```

Comment: Please share your expected output.

Comment: Please check the print: https://ibb.co/cyF47GQ 

This is near what I want, I just would like to be able to add the original column "References" here.

So, for row 2 it would be: A:0; B: VERDADEIRO; C: Reference/ID

Comment: Read this, it does what you want to do with a very detailed guide https://pbpython.com/excel-diff-pandas.html